# Adding router links to a paragraph in Angular NativeScript

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Trying to format a paragraph or sentence that has multiple text links in it. These links would be router links, not external web links.

Looks like you can format text with FormattedString and Span, but also seems you can't add nsRouterLink to a Span.

```
<Label class="terms">
    <FormattedString>
        <Span text="By creating an account, you agree to the our "></Span>
        <Span
            text="Terms of Use"
            class="link"
            [nsRouterLink]="['/policies/terms-of-use']"
            pageTransition="slideLeft"
        ></Span>
        <Span text=" and "></Span>
        <Span
            text="Privacy Policy"
            class="link"
            [nsRouterLink]="['/policies/privacy-policy']"
            pageTransition="slideLeft"
        ></Span>
        <Span text="."></Span>
    </FormattedString>
</Label>
```

If I could have the entire thing clickable I could wrap everything in a button instead, but as you can see in the example, there are two separate links there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately tap event on Span is not supported yet. It's been a [open feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3671) for quite some time.

Though you can find an [example](https://github.com/tsonevn/clickableSpanIOSAndroid) of recognizing tap with bit of native code in Github. You may have to implement the same and call navigate method from the listener.